# Display content of the array/list

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

I'm looking for a way to display (in the `MsgBox` or other read-able place) the array/list content, the `list` contains only strings:

`Dim list As New List(Of String)`

I would like to display the content of it in the `MsgBox` for now. I can convert the `list` to the `array` if there would be a need. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can declare a variable and loop the array putting every element inside:

```
Dim sResult As String = ""

For Each elem As String In list
    sResult &= elem & " "
Next
```

Or you can use [String.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) to directly merge all the elements of the array (you will need to convert the `List` to a normal array if using .NET framework before 4.0):

```
Dim sResult As String = String.Join(", ", list.ToArray())
```

Comment: It's `String.Join` not `List.Join`. Apart from that, with .NET 4 you don't need the new array for [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 6):

How many elements are in that List? If they are few then a MessageBox could do

```
Dim message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.ToArray())
MessageBox.Show(message)
```

If there are many, then you need some kind of interface to display everything.
In this case you need at least a WinForm application with your user defined Form that contains a TextBox with its multiline property set to true.

```
Dim message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.ToArray())
textBox1.Text = message
```

Here a reference to [MSDN docs on List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx)

Comment: With .NET 4 you don't need the new array for [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.100).aspx).